# Sorting related-list records

Tags: related-list

I want to sort related-list records on CreatedDate in ascending. But I don't want to show CreatedDate field in related-list. Any thoughts? Can I use default sorting?

Comment: So is it one time sort or user can sort anytime ?

Comment: Afraid you're looking at a custom vf section style related list. Don't believe you can sort on a column without displaying it in the related list.

Comment: it is one time sort. Actually I don't want use apex.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. Even when tweaking the layout in Eclipse IDE you'll get an error back.

```
Save error: The sort field: CreatedDate is not a displayed field in the related list
```

Can you sort by it indirectly? Maybe you have an autonumber field there?

Comment: I want to sort it by CreatedDate. If I create any autonumber field then I have to display that field as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom VF page and sort a list of sObjects by the field you want it to be sorted on. Simply not show the column CreatedDate.

Sdry's comment proved me wrong (it IS possible), take a look at this aswell: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/A-gift-for-you-Sorting-a-List-lt-sObject-gt/td-p/107833

Comment: With a custom VF page you could always resort to client side sorting, and hiding the column you sort on.

Comment: Oh okay. So you'd be able to sort a list by a specific field and not show the column itself. Am I right?